# Entity Data Source custom Where Parameter, getting NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4, membership

I am trying to implement a custom Where Parameter, so I can show only the currently logged-in user's data.  I use EF4 and SQL Membership.  I get an error that points to my codebehind.

The error is: "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CleaningGridViewEDS.WhereParameters["Username"].DefaultValue = User.Identity.Name;
}
```

AND

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="ShowAllTasksEDS" runat="server"  ConnectionString="name=HmsEntitiesConnectionString"
            DefaultContainerName="HmsEntitiesConnectionString" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="CleaningDatas"
            EnableDelete="true" EnableInsert="true" EnableUpdate="true" OrderBy="it.[DueDate]" AutoGenerateWhereClause="false"
            Where="it.[SubmittedByUserName] == @UserName" >
            <WhereParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="String" />
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: The parmeter name is "UserName" and in Page_Load you use "Username" (name starts with lower case). I think that since there is no Username paramter in the WhereParameters you get a null value. Then you try callin .DefaultValue on the result (which is null) and hence the NullReferenceException.